# Unix epoch time: Adding days

Tags: javascript, unix, datetime

In Javascript, I needed to add one single day to unix epoch timestamp. So, I tried adding 24*60*60*1000 or 86400000 milliseconds to my date, say: 1396306800000, which, as per http://www.epochconverter.com/ is: `4/1/2014 12:00:00 AM GMT+1`. Now, when I try and add one day to it, to get the result, `1396393200000` which is: `4/2/2014 12:00:00 AM GMT+1`.

Just one day, right?

Now, I try and subtract a day from the original `1396306800000` to get `1396220400000` or `3/31/2014 12:00:00 AM GMT+1`

So far, so good.

Now, If I do one more subtraction, I get this: `1396134000000` which is `3/29/2014 11:00:00 PM GMT+0`

How, is this possible? Subsequent subtractions are going smoothly with the same offsets. But at this particular point, 30th March is skipped entirely. Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daylight savings time. Probably [British Summer Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time).

You've probably overlooked the `GMT+1` in

```
3/31/2014 12:00:00 AM GMT+1
```

If you look at the earlier date, it's `GMT+0`:

```
3/29/2014 11:00:00 PM GMT+0
```

The United Kingdom (and other countries) switch time zones on the last sunday of March, which was March 30th this year (2014). The website uses your local time zone settings. This explains the apparent difference of one hour.

Answer (score 1):

It is not skipping a day, you are not accounting for the daylight saving time.

During daylight saving adjustment the day is only 23 hours, which you are subtracting 24hrs from.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the link you provided and also calculated and it's giving the correct result.

So if you subtract one day from 1396306800000 so it becomes 1396220400000=1396306800000-86400000

and the output is

GMT: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 23:00:00 GMT